# Save-Read file from virtual path

Tags: c#

I am using an external dll(library) which i need to set a string with a path( for reading a txt file).
Is it possible to use a string with a virtual path in memory? Instead a physical path?

Comment: As far as I know, not in any easy way. Because of this, APIs should include the option to use a stream instead of a file-path whenever possible. Unfortunately not all API do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read the contents of a file opened from a virtual path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4624760/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-file-opened-from-a-virtual-path)